# Ellipsize is not working with AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

`android:ellipsize="end"` is not working and when I use `android:ellipsize="marquee"`, the app crashes.

Here is my code:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:popupBackground="#000000"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/atw1"
     android:id="@+id/atw2"
     android:hint="Airport" />
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `ellipsize` with an `AutoCompleteTextView`?

Comment: Because my list contains name of Airports concatenated with country airports and i just want to place ellipsize at the end when user selects one item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in xml file

android:completionThreshold="1"